# How to extract json data of the selected nodes using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, json, html, d3.js

I am new in d3.js and using the simple molecule d3 http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3037015 .
My first question is how i can select multiple nodes of the molecule structure?
Second how i can extract the name and size data(that is stored in json file) of the selected nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [small extended version](http://jsbin.com/wumev/1/) of your posted link.

1. Clicking a node will change the color of the node now. You can easily change it in the way you need it. You could also set an additional property or class and then later on check which items have such a property/class. Or you save the clicked items in another JSON and check if they already exists in that list before adding it.
2. Well that is also now in that extended version. If you click a node the atom and size will be printed on the top left side.

Comment: thanks @kwoxer for ur response. By selecting i mean to change the color or stroke. Actually what i want is to select some  atoms from molecule structure and than extract the json data of those selected atoms. I want to display json data that consist of atomic number, atomic mass and name of the selected atoms. I hope you will understant what i meant to be :)

Comment: Well I was bad at chemistry, but I think I know what you want. I create a JSFiddle example for you.

Comment: Well a JSBin because JSFiddle is too laggy for me. Hope you like. If you have questions just let me know.

Comment: Wow cool my first accepted answer. Thank you. In case you need something more let me know. I also mentioned a console error print. I don't know if it comes from JSBin or so. But you should check this =) Good luck.